# gnu parallel: how to control output of program?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Fast and simple. This command works

```
locate -i mymovieormysong|parallel mplayer
```

the song (or movie) play, but i cannot control mplayer with keyboard.
How to do (if possible) this?

Actually when i use keyboard to go forward or backward I obtain this

```
^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[D^[[D^[[D
```

Edit1: using -u (un-group) option, the output appear but when I press keyboard for control mplayer still appear [C and [D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon it is unlikely that you want more than one `mplayer` running.

Normally GNU Parallel takes the tty of the process (due to process group logic). `--tty` hands the tty to the tty running. So if `mplayer` reads from the tty, then this might work:

```
locate -i mymovieormysong|parallel --tty mplayer
```